# \newgeometry for a single page not section

Tags: margins, geometry

My top margin in the whole document is 1 inch, but I want it to be 2 inches only for the pages that are the beginning of a new section. I start each new section on a new page. If For instance, my introduction takes 3 pages. I want only the first page of the introduction to have a 2-inch margin. If I used \newgeometry before the introduction, how can I specify that \restoregeometry takes place on the next page without cutting the text?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Since you always start a new section on a new page, it would seem more effective to patch the definition of `\section` than to try to adjust the page geometry temporarily every time.

Comment: @Enas Which documentclass do you use? From you description, maybe something like the chapters from the book class might be better suited?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I am using the article class. Could you please elaborate on how could the book class be better fin my case?

Comment: @barbarabeeton would you please elaborate more? What do you mean by patching the definition of \section?

Comment: @Enas The chapters in book class automatically start on new pages and have a bigger space on top. I'm not sure which layout you are exactly looking for, but maybe have a look if maybe the book class would automatically do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is a pretty easy fix. I just used this code before each section starts.

```
\vspace*{-40pt + 1in}
```

I have tried using \vspace before but without the * and it was not working for that reason.